# Can I use the same default gateway for a device on a different network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing, gateway, ipv4

Say I have IP 192.168.1.0 and all the IP addresses are taken so I go onto 192.168.2.0 and have 192.168.2.5 available.  When I'm assigning a gateway for the device to access can I use a gateway on the 192.168.1 network?

I know this question is very basic but my issue is that I have a network I do not have the gateway for and have no way of determining it.  My only access point in range is on the hypothetical 192.168.1 network.

Comment: If you configure the subnet as 192.168.1.0/24 then only addresses 192.168.1.0 to 192.168.1.255 are included. But 192.168.0.0/22 includes all addresses from 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.3.255, so all address you mention would be in the same subnet and all would be fine. Bottom line: your question cannot be answered without knowing the subnet mask.

Answer (score 0):

Though there are some exceptions to this in unusual setups, the general answer is no.  You cannot configure your computer to use a gateway that is on a different subnet.

You cannot reach devices on other subnets without going through a router (gateway).  Your system determines that a system is outside of your network by using your address and subnet mask to compute the network you are on.  If the system you are trying to contact is on your local network, and your local network is Ethernet, it will perform an ARP lookup to get the MAC address of the device you want to connect to.  If the destination is not on your local network it will contact the router you have configured for that destination, or the default router.  The router must be on the same layer 2 and 3 network, or you won't be able to reach it to  have it forward your packets.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you're saying and asking But note that the importance of a gateway is to help hosts in the same subnet to reach other networks, forexample The Internet.

Let's take an example of a wireless home router, it assigns hosts IP addresses, DNS server address and the gateway. Let's say WLAN network is 192.168.1.0/24. By default the gateway is always 192.168.1.1, so the devices connected to that network get the gateway IP which is always in the subnet and IP address plus a mask which identifies the network the device is in.

If you change a gateway of a device to lemme say any other address which is not in your WLAN network 192.168.1.0/24, the device not be able to reach the internet because it won't have the correct gateway address assigned to it..

Please Note: The gateway should be in your network, the gateway then forwards to another IP and so on. That's why it's called "routing".

Thank you.